# Angularjs comparing dates

Tags: angularjs, date

I am trying to compare 2 dates and to filter my data with the result:

**my controller:**

```
  $scope.checkDate = function(startDate){
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    return function(coupon){
        return coupon[startDate]<= todaysDate;
    };
}
```

**my html:**

```
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="coupon-tiles" ng-repeat="coupon in allCoupons| filter: checkDate('startDate')" ng-if="coupon.amount>0" >
        <div>
            <image ng-src={{coupon.image}}>
        </div>
        <div>{{coupon.title}}</div>
        <div>price:{{coupon.price}}</div>
        <div>start date:{{coupon.startDate}}</div>
        <div>end date:{{coupon.endDate}}</div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-    click="buy(coupon)">Purchase</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The coupons arrive from the db through json, the dates are java sql dates so the format is yyyy,mm,dd , Jersey and Jackson doing the parsing.

Nothing seems to work, can someone help

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ is a good one to play with dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB dates are in string format. You need to convert it to JS Date object to compare them. Try the following:

```
$scope.checkDate = function(startDate){
var todaysDate = new Date();
 return function(coupon){
    return Date.parse(coupon[startDate]) <= todaysDate;
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your filter function like

```
$scope.checkDate = function(startDate){
    return startDate.getTime() <= new Date().getTime();
}
```

And in your html

```
 <div class="col-sm-3" id="coupon-tiles" ng-repeat="coupon in allCoupons| filter: checkDate(coupon.startDate)" ng-if="coupon.amount>0" >
```

Comment: startDate.getTime() is un defined, this is the error i get.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this and this is working:

```
var startDate = $filter('date')($scope.StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
var endDate = $filter('date')($scope.EndDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
if (startDate > endDate) {
    //some code
}
```

For using `$filter` you need to inject `$filter` in your controller.